# docker-compose v2 run command recreates containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

I'm running tests in multiple steps on CircleCI ubuntu image with docker-compose. First I need to run migrations and after that the actual tests so I have two `docker-compose run` commands. However, the second one is recreating the database containers used in previous step so the migrations are wiped and the tests will fail. How do I prevent docker-compose from recreating the containers?

This started to happen when I updated the CircleCI ubuntu image to the latest, which updated docker-compose from v1 to v2. I'm not able to reproduce this locally on mac with v2.

this is part of what the first `docker-compose run` prints out:

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Network tests_default                Created 0.0s
 ⠋ Container tests-test-db-1     Creating 0.1s
 ⠋ Container tests-test-redis-1  Creating 0.1s
```

This is part what the second `docker-compose run` prints out:

```
 [+] Running 2/2
  ⠿ Container tests-test-redis-1    Recreated 0.2s
  ⠿ Container tests-test-db-1       Recreated 0.3s
  ⠋ Container tests-test-backend-1  Creating 0.0s
```

Comment: do you have depends_on or links? if you you can try with --no-deps

Comment: It indeed has them, but those are required. The setup has the service to run, backend & databases. 4 different services in total. While trying with --no-deps tests fail since all the services are required.

Comment: You can start the required services beforehand in detached mode, potentially leveraging profiles, and then do the run commands with no deps. Or you can use volumes to persist your migrations.

Comment: Is there no way to enforce docker-compose not to recreate them? Since there is discrepancy between CircleCI ubuntu & macOS & docker-compose v1, it seems that recreating should not be mandatory but for some reason always happens on CircleCI ubuntu only. I saw that docker-compose up does have --no-recreate flag, but run does not have it.

Comment: We are running into the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: The way I fixed it was to ensure that I only need to run docker-compose run once. Previously we set up database with one docker-compose run and ran tests with subsequent docker-compose run. Now we run it once and that command does both. I'd like to keep them separate, but the recreate issue forced to combine them.